# Specific php5 mod_rewrite rule to process a user-entered short url server side?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I browsed the plethora of answers here but couldn't find one specific enough to mimic for my needs. I'm not looking to create a shortened URL, I'm looking for a way for the server to detect the format of a shortened URL, expand it and display the page normally (and of course without changing the look of the shortened URL in the actual browser URL bar). Here's what I'd like to do...

I have the following url structure:

```
http://www.mysite.com/members.php?user_name
```

I'd like users to access these dynamic pages using shortened URLs. They should be able to access this same page by typing in:

```
http://www.mysite.com/users/user_name
```

..and the mod_rewrite rule would know to parse it as the full url above. Any ideas how this would be written? Notice the parameter is not passed with a value.

PS: Not looking to mess with any of the application code or parameters, just looking for a rule to simply read the short URL and covert server-side, if at all possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/users/(.*) /members.php?$1 [l]
```

<del>This makes the assumption that any url that doesn't map to an existing directory or file should be considered a user_name.</del>

EDIT: Changed rule to match updated question. You should really read the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/). Also based on the updated URL the two `RewriteCond` may not be necessary.

Comment: I had a typo in my shortened URL example above. Users should be able to type in: `http://www.mysite.com/users/user_name` and the server would rewrite to the full URL. Sorry for the confusion! How would you modify that example to work in this way?

Comment: Thanks for the update, but adding those rules yields a 'page not found' error. Just so we're clear, those rules should be telling the server to take `http://www.mysite.com/users/user_name` but interpret it as `http://www.mysite.com/members.php?user_name` correct?

Comment: @mindScuplt, you may need to drop one of the `/` from the `RewriteRule`. It really just depends on where in the config you're applying this rule. You can use `RewriteLog` to debug.

Comment: Ok, so the following works - almost: `RewriteRule ^users/(.*) /members.php?$1 [l]`

However now all the css/image/script paths are looking within the 'fake' URL for them, which they obviously don't exist. Will absolute links fix that, or is there a better way to ensure it through another mod_rewrite rule?

Comment: UPDATE: To answer part of my own previous comment's question, absolute links WILL fix this issue. Still wondering if there's a mod_rewrite rule that could take care of this too...

Comment: @MindSculpt Yes and No. Yes -- rewrite rule will fix it if you explain Apache how to rewrite it for EACH location, which is completely wrong way of doing it (but yes -- it can be done). If you do this you will have the same image/css/js accessible via different URLs -- which is plain wrong and inefficient. The proper answer is **No** -- use absolute URLs for your images/styles/js

Comment: Mod_rewrite cannot change URLs in the HTML output. You could however add a rule to map the links back to the old location. But probably not what you really want to do.

Comment: @matthew Yeah, absolute URLs is easier and makes more sense. Thanks guys!

Comment: @matthew Follow-up question: Suppose you are using something like Facebook connect from one of these pages, which returns the user back to

`http://www.mysite.com/users/user_name`

but adds a whole bunch of session params afterwards, like 

`http://www.mysite.com/users/user_name?session=XXXXXX&session_key=XXXXXX`

Is it possible to then also handle the vanity URL so the server reads it as: 

`http://www.mysite.com/members.php?user_name&session=XXXXXX&session_key=XXXXXX`

Comment: Change the the `[L]` to `[L,QSA]` which will append the submitted query string to the rewritten request.